# google places api - events

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-places

While we can add events and events will be returned with search result, I am not sure how are the events 'searched'.

Because I see that when we add events, we are not able to define types. Say a concert. So when users are searching, what kind of search will list the concert event as result?

Comment: "Events" are not social events, but application events.

Comment: They added support for [events](http://googlegeodevelopers.blogspot.com/2012/05/events-support-in-google-places-api.html) to the Places API (not the application kind...)